# How to allow firebase user to only access documents that they created (rules_version = '2')

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I know that already exists an [answer to this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58249305/how-to-allow-firebase-user-to-only-access-documents-that-they-created), but I guess my use case is a little bit different.

I have two collections on firestore: "users" and "templates"

Each time I create a user, I create a template and assign the template id to the same user id as you can see below.

** Repository.js **

```js
async createUser(email, password) {
    const template = await getLocalTemplate()
    const credentials = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

    await db.collection('users').doc(credentials.user.uid).set({ email })
    await db.collection('templates').doc(credentials.user.uid).set({
      ...template,
    })
    
    return credentials
  }
```

However, I don't know how to allow users do write only to its templates.

These are my firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /users/{user} {
      allow create
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user
    }
    
    match /templates/{template} {
      allow read, create
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == /users/{user}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follows. By using the `{template}` wildcard, it makes the `template` variable available in your rule.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read: ...;  
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == user;
    }
    
    match /templates/{template} {
      allow read: ...;  
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == template;
    }
  }
}
```

---

You may use the same rule for `read` and `write` as follows:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == template;
```