# How do I use doc and firestore with @angular/fire/firestore to access the database and insert a record

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have been attempting to use the following code to add a user to firestore and then  add a user record in the database.
I have been able to add a user and receive the proper returns, but on

```
doc(this.firestore, `users/${credentials.user.uid}`);
```

I receive the error

fail with FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Auth,createUserWithEmailAndPassword,sendPasswordResetEmail,signInWithEmailAndPassword,     signOut} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { doc, Firestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { setDoc } from '@firebase/firestore';

constructor(private auth: Auth, private firestore: Firestore) { 
}


async register({ email, password }: { email: string; password: string }) {
  try {
    const credentials = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.auth,
      email,
      password
    ); // returns uid and access tokens etc..
  
    const ref = doc(this.firestore, `users/${credentials.user.uid}`);  // get a document reference
    // fail with FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

    setDoc(ref, { email });// set to referenced document 
    return credentials;    
  } catch (e) {
     return null;    
   }
```

}

I have tried to copy exactly from the docs:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire

```
 import { doc, collection } from '@angular/fire/firestore'; // doc collection fail, it seems and get or insert into the database fails
```

and still I receive the same error.  Does anyone have any experience using angularfire 7.6.1 with ionic 7 and capacitor 5, or know of an example of referencing a Firebase document with latest ionic versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in node modules /angularFire v7.6.1 @firebase / rxfire / CountSnapshot exports and imports. I commented some of them out depending on firestore function and it worked.  The is not an ideal solution as new errors are sure to follow.  The only course of action I see is waiting for the new AngularFire release as they are aware of this problem and are working on a solution.

Answer (score 3):

With [Angular Fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) 7.x and later, you can directly use Angular's [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action) to get an instance of Firestore. Once you get the instance, you can easily use it to access collections and documents.

Import [`AngularFirestore`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/5793d6f3a15aa61660af75ab361c534cde9b73df/src/compat/firestore/firestore.ts#L121) instead of `Firestore` from `@angular/fire/firestore`, and update the constructor argument from `private firestore: Firestore` to `private firestore: AngularFirestore`.
(`AngularFirestore` is a wrapper around the native Firestore service, customized to integrate better with Angular applications. It provides Angular-friendly observables and methods that take advantage of Angular's features).

Then use `this.firestore.collection('users').doc(credentials.user.uid)` to get a `DocumentReference` (as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63038857/6309)).

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, sendPasswordResetEmail, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore'; // Import AngularFirestore

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private auth: Auth, private firestore: AngularFirestore) { // Change Firestore to AngularFirestore
  }

  async register({ email, password }: { email: string; password: string }) {
    try {
      const credentials = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        this.auth,
        email,
        password
      );

      // Now, use AngularFirestore instance to access the Firestore
      const userDoc = this.firestore.collection('users').doc(credentials.user.uid);
      await userDoc.set({ email });

      return credentials;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3422) while trying to solve the same issue myself.

On this thread, someone suggests to import `collection()` from `'firebase/firestore'` instead of `'@angular/fire/firestore'` :

```
import { Firestore, collectionData } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { collection } from 'firebase/firestore';
```

It worked for me. Not ideal but still a solution until the new AngularFire is released as Thomas explained in his answer.

Comment: One thing I did was to add @ to import @firebase/firestore

Answer (score 0):

The error message you’re seeing, FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore, indicates that the first argument passed to the collection() function is not of the expected type. This error can occur when the firestore object is not properly initialized or when it is not an instance of FirebaseFirestore.

In your code, you are using the Firestore class from the @angular/fire/firestore module to create a new instance of the firestore object and passing it to the doc() function. However, it is possible that this object is not being properly initialized or that it is not an instance of FirebaseFirestore.

One possible solution is to ensure that you are importing and using the correct classes and functions from the @angular/fire/firestore module. You can try importing the getFirestore function from the @angular/fire/firestore module and using it to create a new instance of the firestore object, like this:

```
import { getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

// ...

constructor(private auth: Auth) {
  this.firestore = getFirestore();
}

// ...
```

Hope this helps,
Und3fined

Comment: I wanted to edit it but the queue is full.